# Capybara 2.0 and rspec-rails -- helpers don't work in spec/features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, helper

I'm trying to use a method from a helper module, but rspec doesn't seem to recognize helpers for tests under `spec/features`. Note that the only change to `spec_helper.rb` was adding `require 'capybara/rspec'`.

I tried moving `helper.rb` to `spec/support`, `spec/helpers`, and `spec/features` (the directory that contains my tests), but no luck. The test keeps indicating that the helper method is undefined.

The only way to get it to "work" was by moving my test to a different directory, such as `spec/integration`. But now capybara won't work (`visit undefined`) because it's not in `spec/features`.

Here's my helper module (`authentication_helper.rb`):

```
module AuthenticationHelper
    def sign_in_as!(user)
        visit '/users/sign_in'
        fill_in "Email", with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: "password"
        click_button "Sign in"
        page.should have_content("Signed in successfully.")
    end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
    c.include AuthenticationHelper, type: :request
end
```

Comment: did you try: `c.include AuthenticationHelper, type: :feature`

Comment: I just tried it, but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I found a solution: I moved the *_spec.rb files to spec/integration directory and added config.include Capybara::DSL to spec_helper. 

It seems like I can even move the *_spec.rb files to spec/requests.

But I'm still a bit on the eery side that this isn't the standard way to do it, as capybara 2 recommends putting the spec files into spec/features. But at the same time, I'm pretty new to the software development world, so I could be worrying about nothing.

I don't know, what do you guys think? Should I look for a better way or leave as is?

Comment: Oh wow. I was pretty darn sure I tried what you suggested--I even remember it being :feature and not :features because I doubled checked. It might have been something to do with rspec-rails 2.13.1, because after updating it to 2.13.2, it worked! Thanks! I'm not sure how to accept a comment as an answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

put this helper file in spec/support/

and this line spec_helper.rb

```
  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: spec_helper.rb already had that as default, unfortunately. Again, the only change I've made to the spec_helper.rb file was adding require 'capybara/rspec'

Comment: after doing above steps add 'include AuthenticationHelper' be the require statements

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but I see where you're going with this. Sadly, this isn't the solution I'm looking for since there may be additional tests that require the module. Although feasible, I'd prefer to use a feature provided by rspec (that doesn't seem to work out of the box atm) and make this easier on me and potentially others as well.