# uninitialized constant TestFactories (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factories

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails and I am writing a "User sign in" spec for a wiki project, and I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant TestFactories (NameError)
```

This is my sign_in_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Sign in flow" do

    include TestFactories 

    before do
        @user = authenticated_user
    end

    describe "successful" do
        it "redirects user to the wikis index" do
            user = authenticated_user
            visit root_path
        end
    end
end
```

This is my test_factories.rb file:

```
module TestFactories

    def authenticated_user(options={})
        user_options = { email: "email#{rand}@fake.com", password: 'password' }.merge(options)
        user = User.new(user_options)
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save
        user
    end

end
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
    gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


# Testing
group :develpment, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails' 
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

# Databases
# Developemnt
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: Why dont u put your authenticated_user method in spec_helper?

Answer (score 0):

or you can do something like this in sepc helper

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include TestFactories
end
```

Comment: Where does your test_factories.rb resides?

Comment: it's in spec/features/support/test_factories.rb

Comment: try removing include statement and refer to some of these answers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610536/include-helper-not-works

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691590/capybara-2-0-and-rspec-rails-helpers-dont-work-in-spec-features